# Update second column into one

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update multiple colums into one column of an another table:
I am using MS SQl Server

Table 1:

```
Num | ColumnA | ColumnB  |
--------------------------
1   | Peter   | Mueller  |
1   | Jonny   | Corleone |
2   | John    | Cohn     |
1   | Sarah   | Wood     |
```

Now I want to update ColumnA and ColumnB into ColumA of Table2 like this:

Table2:

```
Num | ColumnC                                      |
----------------------------------------------------
1   | Peter, Mueller, Jonny, Corleone, Sarah, Wood |
2   | John, Cohn                                   |
```

Comment: If you're planning to query ColumnC and use the values in it at any point, I would advise against doing this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good practice to store multiple values in a single column. If you need to do this though, then try this:

```
SELECT adress,
       num,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + ColumnA + ',' + ColumnB
              FROM   table1 a
              WHERE  a.Num = b.Num
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   table1 b
GROUP  BY num
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to get more columns but it doesn't work: Like this: select adress, num, Stuff(( Stuff((SELECT ',' + ColumnA + ',' + ColumnB
              FROM   table1 a
              WHERE  a.Num = b.Num
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM   table1 b
GROUP  BY num

Comment: @machupichu - you have added one extra `stuff` which is not needed just add `adress` in select column list. I have updated my answer check now